# Select query without exact match using % Wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have almost solved a problem here and I need help, by using this code

```
SELECT *
FROM  new_products
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT ProductID
  FROM old_products
  WHERE 
         old_products.ProductID
         LIKE
         new_products.ProductID
)
```

This is supose to bring me the items from new_products that are not on old_products (just the new products to be selected).

However when the product id varchar is like '91 or 91b' it is not found, only if in both tables they are the **exact same** varchar.

I tried using something like (like %ProductID%) doing by this:

```
    WHERE 
           old_products.ProductID 
           LIKE 
           ('%' + new_products.ProductID + '%')
```

However the results are not working at all, it considers item that are in both as unique and vice versa. Any help ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using?  You have three tagged.  And how are the results not what you expected?

Comment: Methinks this is a case where you think MySQL refers to SQL you have written and that SQL Server is a Server that runs SQL. This is not the case they are actually two separate products. My guess is you're actually running SQLite is this correct?

Comment: I thought it would grant more viewers, thought SQL language didn't differed that much, sorry about that. I am Using MySQL Community. Basically It returns the items that does not exist in the second table but only if it is exactly the same item. For example: Item '95' is found in varchar = '95' but varchar = '95 or 91' is considered a new Item. I need it to be able to see if the item is in the middle of the varchar not only the exact same varchar.

Comment: Siyual the results are just wrong. When I don't use the % it doesn't look in the middle of the varchar's just the whole varchar. When I use the % it considers old items as new and vice versa. The objetive is to detect which products are new and not in the old catalog using the NMontadora product id. btw: edited for better reading the code.

Comment: It would help if you gave us some sample data and what you expect the outcome to be.

Comment: The `LIKE` operator simply doesn't do what you want it to do.  It does not perform fuzzy matching (as its name does suggest), but rather pattern matching.  Therefore, it is almost never correct to test `some_table.col1 LIKE another_table.col2`, or anything similar.  It is rare for the right-hand operand of a useful `LIKE` expression to be anything other than a constant string.

Comment: The question, then, is exactly how the `new_products.productID`s you want to exclude correspond to `old_products.productId`s, and how to distinguish those cases from any similar ones that you do not want to exclude.

Comment: just use `REGEXP` instead of `like` in your first query

Comment: Thanks @Farhęg it worked like a charm ! I'll still need to fix some bad feeding in the inventory (extra spaces and etc) but this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL your expression  ('%' + new_products.ProductID + '%') probably evaluates to 0.
Try this instead :

```
CONCAT('%' , new_products.ProductID , '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it as user @Farhęg suggested. Changing like for REGEXP actually worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And just to point out for the future, this is MYSQL specific syntax. That is why it is critical to always state which  database backend you are working with as flavors of SQL vary considerably.

Comment: Indeed. I used SQL in work two times in my life (once mssql and now mysql), I knew that some functions where flavor exclusive but didnt know so there are so many differences. I removed the sql server tag as soon as I understood this. Thanks